# Is there really no DEFAULT class for swiping left or right?

Tags: java, android, view, swipe

I'm in the process of making an app that slides facts across the screen left and right, my issue is that I cannot find a default class to do this, instead a VERY SIMPLE action that is commonly used needs this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
 {     
     switch(event.getAction())
     {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           x1 = event.getX();                         
   break;         
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       x2 = event.getX();
       float deltaX = x2 - x1;
       if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
       {
         Toast.makeText(this, "left2right swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
       }
       else
       {
           // consider as something else - a screen tap for example
       }                          
   break;   
 }           
 return super.onTouchEvent(event);       
 }
```

or something equally as difficult and foreign for a BASIC MOVEMENT.

Is there an easier way? I find unacceptable for an SDK of such a massive OS to not have a default class to handle this, especially since there's an 'ACTION_' for just about everything except left and right.

Comment: Try using ViewPager for your task. You can swipe between different pages.

Answer (score 3):

Many high-level use cases can be handled by `ViewPager`, `HorizontalScrollView`, or `RecyclerView`. There is also the deprecated `Gallery` widget.

Many lower-level use cases can be handled by `GestureDetector`, such as the family of solutions on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures). However, you have to define exactly what constitutes "BASIC MOVEMENT" (to use your shouty term).

There is also the [old `GestureLibrary` stuff](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureLibrary.html), which I haven't seen used in ages, so I don't know if it is still practical.

There are also [many libraries that offer swipe options](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=swipe) for different scenarios (e.g., swipe-to-dismiss in list rows).

In the future, you might consider providing a more concrete scenario (and less whining), to get more specific recommendations. Your description of "slides facts across the screen left and right" is rather vague.

Comment: I have a textview in the centre of the screen and I want it to change based on whether they swipe left or right (to go forward or back a fact).

Comment: @420blazeit: Usually, for swipe gestures, you want the thing being swiped to move, to show visual feedback to the user. You do not appear to want that, so the high-level solutions that I listed will not work for you. One of the libraries might handle that, though I am not aware of any that would. The `GestureDetector` options would be your best bet. Or, reconsider your UI, to use patterns that the user might already be used to and that fit existing supported scenarios.

Comment: @420blazeit: Now, if I misinterpreted your "have a textview in the centre of the screen" part, and you mean that you want it to start in the center, but then follow the finger and be swiped off... then `ViewPager` is what you want. It handles all the gesture stuff for you; you just tell it how many pages there are and what the page contents are (`Views` or `Fragments`).

Comment: What I was originally looking to do was make it so swiping left or right acted as an action listener and then the textview text changes instantly when they swipe. How would I do this? Similar to this:

`swipe.OnSwipeLeft(){`

`textview.setText("You swiped Left!");`

`}`

Comment: @420blazeit: Again, that's not especially typical of modern touchscreen UIs, which is why you are going to have to deal with lower-level stuff yourself. `GestureDetector`, using the stuff from [the question that I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures), would be your best bet.